# Outlook collapse of table cells in HTML emails

Tags: outlook, html-email, html-rendering

I have come across this issue and have yet to be able to find a solution to it. With an html e-mail I have found that in some Outlook programs it will collapse the cell. Both 2007/2010 For instance:

```
<tr>
    <td width="10"><img></td>
    <td width="80">Copy</td>
    <td width="10"><img></td>
</tr>
```

What happens is that Outlook ignores the width of the middle column's cell. It also doesn't matter if I use CSS for the widths.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:10px;"><img></td>
    <td style="width:80px;">Copy</td>
    <td style="width:10px;"><img></td>
</tr>
```

This has the same results.

The thing I haven't been able to figure out, is the setting in Outlook that causes this collapsing of the cell's width. And typically, it only happens in Outlook for the CEO of our company. I no longer code a cell with copy in it this way anymore as I have a more rock solid way that works, but sometimes marketing thinks they know what they are doing and changes the code on me thinking it will work, when I know it will not on the CEO's computer in Outlook.

Does anybody know what setting in Outlook causes this? I'd love to have this setting on my computer so I don't need to but the CEO to test it.

Comment: Dealing with the same issue. Please post your answer when you find out. Looking at the source of the HTML as rendered in Outlook is as far as I've gotten. The tables have NEW, unspecified by me, dimensions, in points!

Comment: 1) width (when spelled correctly) should not have CSS styling. Width is either designated in pixels (width="80") or you can designate percentages (width="20%")   2) add &nbsp; into empty elements   3) add inline CSS (style="font-size;NNpx; line-height:NNpx;") for any element that has text, even if it is a non-breaking space, and lastly, declare background-color (bgcolor="#FFFFFF") with 6-length HEX regardless of whether the item has content or not because Outlook treats un-colored cells poorly. See CampaignMonitor website for other tips.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a more extensive code example w/ a whole table and not just one row? Would help give a clue why this is happening.

Anyway, something that works for me in Outlook is to add a top row in the table that forces the column widths to exact heights. A 1x1 transparent GIF, with widths set in addition to table cell widths, seems to work as a 'brute force' method that even Outlook listens to:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="10" height="1"><img width="10" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="80" height="1"><img width="80" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="10" height="1"><img width="10" height="1" /></td>
  </tr>
```

and then rows beneath that conform to the column widths of that top row.

Comment: This isn't really about "is the code right", it has more to do with the setting in Outlook that causes it. I know why it happens, I don't know what the setting is in Outlook that causes the table to collapse.

I never would code it this way. Marketing loves to mess with the code when they are not supposed to, because they *think* they know what they are doing. I just don't want to have to bother the CEO of the company just to get the proof/example to show Marketing they are wrong. I want that setting enabled on my computer instead.

Comment: Yeah I work for a Marketing department too, I know how that goes! So I was working with the assumption that one has no control over the recipients' individual email clients' settings and need a "safe" way of coding it that works as broadly as possible. Sorry I misunderstood the question. Thing is, I'm not sure there is an available setting in Outlook available to change that behavior--it's probably buried in Outlook's HTML rendering engine which AFAIK doesn't offer users configuration options. If a bigger Outlook expert knows differently I hope they post a better answer.

Comment: Brute force (1px images) has failed in newer versions of outlook making cells expand. If there is no content in a cell, I would suggest to add &nbsp; inside cells. Also, avoid colspans.  http://www.activecampaign.com/email-design-guide/

Comment: Avoiding colspans can get pretty hairy (but of course is possible, with enough nested tables I suppose), but yeah, I have found that were the transparent 1x1 gif doesn't work, filling a cell with &nbsp; will.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue in Outlook 2013 for Windows. It worked fine in Outlook for Mac (and Gmail, and pretty much every other modern email client) but in Outlook 2013 for Windows, it would completely collapse everything.

The solution was simple: do NOT put in px if you are declaring a pixel width (with the exception of inline styles). You have to be really old school. Here was my final (working) code:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>

    <td width="1" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="#"></td>
    <td width="150" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;"><a style="color: #5f6062; text-decoration: none;" href="#">SECTION 1</a></span></td>

    <td width="150" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;"><a style="color: #5f6062; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none;" href="#">SECTION 2</a></span></td>

    <td width="150" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;"><a style="color: #5f6062; text-decoration: none;" href="#">SECTION 3</a></span></td>

    <td width="149" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;"><a style="color: #5f6062; text-decoration: none;" href="#">SECTION 4</a></span></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
```